# ¿Error de sintaxis de php o laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-6

Estoy haciendo un curso de laravel 6 pero al hacer un modelo e ingresar return me arroja error de sintaxis al poner related: y al quintar related: el error desaparece, ¿el error es de php en sintaxis o de laravel?

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Blog extends Model
 {
 protected $guarded = ["id"];

 public function posts () {
    return $this->hasMany( related: Post::class);
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Agrega el error que obtienes tal cual aparece por favor, además no es válido ese doble return en una función

Comment: Es un error de sintáxis. La forma correcta de hacer una relación es `return $this->hasMany(Post::class);`, para más información, mira [acá](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Además ese related no es necesario, parece una ayuda de tu ide así que basta con removerlo

Comment: @BetaM si entiendo que no es posible dos return en la función, hay una extensión para vs code para la sintaxis encontrar errores más facil.

Comment: Sería más simple de evitar dichos errores si te guías por la doc. Oficial que muestra la sintaxis adecuada ;)

Comment: Creo que seria ambas, php y laravel, porque lo logico en php es que no es posible 2 returns

Answer (score 1):

yo lo hago de la siguiente manera y me funciona bien,

en el modelo Post eliminer el : **protected $guarded = ["id"]**

definición de

**$guarded**, el  atributo le dice al modelo que los atributos enumerados en él no están disponibles para asignación masiva.
solo se utilizar para la contraseña

recomendaciones si el campo foraneo se llama **post_id** en hasmany se recomienda utilizar un nombre diferente ejemplo **post_id_all**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Blog extends Model
 {
 //protected $guarded = ["id"];

   public function posts(){
          return $this->HasMany('App\Models\Post', 'post_id');
   }
 }
```

Comment: El método es `hasMany`

Comment: Pueden cerrar la pregunta por favor ya fue resulta